# Unable To Access My Widgets In Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

For some reason when I try and access and change my widgets I can't find them on the component tree.

[image]

Comment: try the `text` tab, that is right next to the `design` tab at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two xml layouts involved here. You are looking at activity_main.xml, and in the bit you've circled on the screenshot you'll see it says `include - @layout/content_main` this means that the contents of content_main.xml will be displayed within the activity_main.xml layout.

If you want to see what's actually in content_main.xml you'll find it in your  project folders on the left under res > layout. When you open up content_main.xml that's where you should find the widgets you're looking for.